# SNMP extension crashes my php 5.6.7 and 5.6.10 (windows 8)

Tags: php-extension, php-5.6, snmp-extension

I was using **php 5.4** fine with its `php_snmp.dll` enabled, but as soon as I upgraded to **php 5.6.7**, I cannot use `php_snmp.dll` anymore.

I just upgraded to **php 5.6.10** hoping that snmp problem would be fixed but its not.
If I comment out that line in php.ini php does not crash and my apache 2.4 webserver starts and runs fine.

Does anyone have this issue with above mentioned php versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just found a comment in **[here](http://put.hk/article/news.php.net/php.bugs/187845/Bug-68001-Fbk-Nab-php-crashes-with-enabled-php-snmp-dll.html)** that helped me solve the issue.

Basically in `c:\usr\snmp\persist\mib_indexes\` directory I found two files named **0** and **1**. If you remove them SNMP extension works fine.